# Файловый менеджер Elfinder "Данные не формате JSON"

Tags: fileupload, umi

В umi.cms встроен файловый менеджер elfinder.
С некоторых неизвестно каких пор, при попытке загрузить файл через админку elfinder не может показать содержимое директории для загрузки файлов.(папки images и file)

При попытке отобразить директорию с файлами пишет: "Данные не формате JSON".

Права на директории с файлами стоят 777.

В логах чисто, в консоли тоже.

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вот здесь похожая ситуация: http://umihelp.ru/forum/index.php?topic=1352.0
Решили отключением debug

Comment: Здравствуйте. debug и не был включен

Comment: я бы в техподдержку попробовал написать или обновил бы систему (если обновлений нет, то принудительно). Если бы не помогло или не было бы возможности, нашел бы запрос, в котором возникает ошибка и полез бы в исходники. Еще можно выгрузить весь проект и найти, где встречается сообщение "Данные не формате JSON" и от этого уже копать дальше. Наверно очевидные вещи, но не могу предложить какого-то более конкретного решения.

Comment: пробовал выгрузить сайт на локальный сервер , чтобы исправить возможные ошибки.   Но лицензия естественно не дает ничего сделать, просит лицензию и ничего не сделать. На боевом сервер не могу включить дегаб, о чем меня просила техподдержка, чтобы найти ошибку. Так как ккуча ошибок на странице отпугнет всех посетителей моего сайта.

Comment: debug можно включить только для определенных ip-адресов.
Вывод ошибок только для посетителей с указанными:
filter.ip[] = "127.0.0.1"